# Exercise 3.6.8 from "How to prove it"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

The exercise:
[image]

> 8. Let $\mathit{U}$ be any set.
>    (a) Prove that for every $\mathit{A} \in \mathscr{P}(\mathit{U})$ there is a unique $\mathit{B} \in \mathscr{P}(\mathit{U})$ such that for every $\mathit{C} \in \mathscr{P}(\mathit{U})$, $\mathit{C} \setminus \mathit{A} = \mathit{C} \cap \mathit{B}$.

How do I start solving this?

On my own, I tried to do it like this:

Let $A$ be arbitrary.
Let $B$ be just a variable (since at this point i have no idea what it's supposed to be)
Let $C$ be arbitrary.
Suppose $a\in C\setminus A$.
I need to prove $a\in C\cap B$.

But I have no idea what $B$ even is, so im stuck.
I think the question right now is, what should $B$ defined as such that when $a\in C\setminus A$, then also $a\in B$?
And $B$ also needs to be unique, which needs to be kept in mind.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your $A \subseteq U$, define $B = U \setminus A$. Then for any $C \subseteq A$:
$$
C \cap B = C \cap (U \setminus A) = (C \cap U) \setminus (C \cap A) = C \setminus (C \cap A) = C \setminus A
$$ as desired.

Comment: How did you come up with the definition for $B$? What was your thought process behind it? Did you do some scratch work that lead you to this conclusion, or was it obvious to you that $B$ must be $U\setminus A$?

Comment: @enoopreuse22 I just plugged $C = U$ into the condition $C \setminus A = C \cap B$; that also shows uniqueness

Comment: how would you prove uniqueness?
Here's my version:
"For any $A\subset U$, suppose that $B\prime\subset U$ and for any $C\subset U$, $C\setminus A=C\cap B\prime$. Plugging in $C=U$, we see that $U\setminus A=U\cup B\prime$. Since $U\cup B\prime = B\prime$, $B\prime = U\setminus A = B$

Comment: @enoopreuse22 yes that works aside from the typo $U \cup B'$ which should be $U \cap B'$

Comment: is the wording good? Would you change it at all?

Answer (score 4):

You're unlikely to be able to complete the proof if you have no idea what $B$ should be. At this point (or even before you start trying to write the proof), consider some examples, try to visualize the relevant Venn diagram, etc. and improve your intuition about the situation.

Given a set $A$, you need to express the operation of "subtracting $A$ from a set" ($C\setminus A$) as "intersecting the set with $B$" ($C\cap B$). Subtracting $A$ means keeping only the elements that are *not* in $A$, which can be regarded as taking an intersection with the set of all elements not in $A$. So the $B$ you're looking for is the complement of $A$.